# C program circular array rotation

Tags: c, programming-challenge, array, time-limit-exceeded

I'm trying to solve a Hackerrank problem where you perform `k` `array[n]` rotations, and at the end, ask for `m` and print `array[m]`. My program is probably correct (it runs perfectly for most of tests, but some of them terminate due to timeout), but is inefficient and I don't know how to improve it.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(){
    int n; 
    int k; 
    int q; 
    scanf("%d %d %d",&n,&k,&q);
    int *a = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    int *b = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    for(int a_i = 0; a_i < n; a_i++){
       scanf("%d",&a[a_i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++){
        b[0] = a[n-1];
        for(int a_i = 1; a_i < n; a_i++){
        b[a_i] = a[a_i-1];
        }
        for(int a_i = 0; a_i < n; a_i++) a[a_i] = b[a_i];
    }
    for(int a0 = 0; a0 < q; a0++){
    int m; 
    scanf("%d",&m);
    printf("%d\n", b[m]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do not do actual rotation.

`k` rotations (from your code I understand that all rotations are to the right by 1) map an `i`'th element to an `(i + k) % n` position. At the time of printing, do some math to figure out which element was mapped to the position `m`.

The math is trivial, and I intentionally do not spell it out.

Comment: Exactly that. Don' move the data. Adjust the indexes to the data.

Comment: If the data really must be moved, it could be done in one step instead of k steps though, and even in-place (by using xor).